# ¿Como cambiar la clase de un DIV segun el ancho del navegador?

Tags: javascript

¿Como cambiar la clase de un DIV según el ancho del navegador?

Estoy intentando captar el ancho del navegador y con el alert compruebo que esta parte si funciona, pero no los remove y add no se ejecutan, no se porqué.

```
window.onload = function() {

   if(window.innerWidth<1000){
     var element1 = document.getElementById("mapa");
     element1.classList.remove("col-md-6");
     element1.classList.add("tab-pane");
     element1.classList.add("fade");
     element1.classList.add("show");
     element1.classList.add("active");

     var element2 = document.getElementById("cuidadores");
     element2.classList.remove("col-md-6");
     element2.classList.add("tab-pane");
     element2.classList.add("fade");   
   }   
   alert(window.innerWidth); 
};
```

Comment: Por qué no mejor usas un media query de css? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con jquery, utilizando el método `.resize()`[resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) y con `$(window).width();` obtienes el ancho de la pantalla.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){

  if($(window).width() < 1000){
    console.log($(window).width());
   
    
  }else{
  
    console.log($(window).width());
   
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sólo se muestra cómo obtener el tamaño de la pantalla con jquery (cuando el usuario no necesita incluír una librería completa sólo para obtener el tamaño de su pantalla) y no se muestra cómo cambiar la clase dependiendo de estos tamaños.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la regla de css `@media` para ello sin necesidad de cambiar de clase, la misma clase se puede adaptar dependiendo del tamaño aquí dos ejemplos:

Puedes tener dos hojas de estilos con las mismas clases y que se aplique una u otra dependiendo el tamaño de la pantalla

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 399px)" href="estilos_de_movil.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 400px)" href="estilos_de_tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1000px)" href="estilos_de_computadora.css" />
```

La otra forma de hacerlo es en la misma hoja de estilos definir las diferencias de las clases dependiendo de los tamaños

```
<style>

.clase {
    background:white;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .clase {
        background:red;
    }

}
</style>
```